# Just getting started with Linux

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

Heyo!  Very excited to get using Linux.  I'm a low level IT support tech and am used to windows, and never considered Linux just because there wasn't any reason to do so.

Picked up a free Lattitude E6500 with 4GB RAM, slapped a 256GB Crucial MX100 SSD in it, and installed windows 10 tech preview.  Realized this would be a great time to try out linux as well, since this laptop is going to be my testbed, and Ubuntu seemed to be the way to go.

Anyway, just wanted to give some background so you all know I have zero knowledge of this OS. :)

Now the question:
I've researched a bit on how to get Ubuntu installed, but am still a little confused as to how to do so properly with my current setup.  I shrunk my win10 partition to 100GB, leaving the remaining 130-140GB as a simple volume (RAW).

I put the CD in, rebooted, and started the process.  However, it doesn't detect a current OS, so I go to 'Something else' option.

From there I learned from a youtube video to select the blank partition (free space) added the following:
root partition - 25GB
swap partition - 8GB

This was my second go around, as I only selected 1GB for the swap file last time.
Also, last time, I also created a boot partition (also, the size of the entire partition was smaller, as was the root partition).

This time, When it was done installing, I got a boot error and was stuck at the grub recovery screen.  I put the CD back in and rebooted, and this time I got an option to install Ubuntu over the existing one.

Installation went fine, but now I have no Win10 to boot into. :)
When I look at the disk size in the Ubuntu OS, it shows 231GB free and 4.1GB used.  It appears to have just done a full install, overwriting the entire drive.

No biggie, and I'm glad it did, in a way, as I'm guessing I'll learn a lot from this!

Please let me know what I did wrong, and if you need any more info.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sentence has all answers:

> This time, When it was done installing, I got a boot error and was
>   stuck at the grub recovery screen. I put the CD back in and rebooted,
>   and this time I got an ***option to install Ubuntu over the existing
>   one.***

Installing over existing once erased Windows and installed Ubuntu over your laptop.

Same happened to me and I am windows free since April 2014. :)

Comment: Yeah, I might eventually get there, but I want to be testing Win10 as well.

Comment: I guess my other questions are:
Can I now install Win10?  If so, what do I have to do since I'm installing it second.
I'd like to also reinstall win10 over everything, and then try the ubuntu partition install again, to learn.  Please give me a basic breakdown of what I need to do for setting up the free space correctly.